# I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading: 0)" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to make a quiz app using React (using API).

API Link:- (https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple)

But I am getting an error in the console saying the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAHX3.png)

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [answer,setAnswer]= React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(()=>{
      fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
      .then((res)=> res.json())
      .then(data => setAnswer(data.results[3]))
    }, [])

  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{answer.question}</h1>
      <h2>{answer.incorrect_answers[0]}</h2>
      <h2>{answer.correct_answer}</h2>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error is in the line 24:1 which is:

```
<h2>{answer.incorrect_answers[0]}</h2>
```

When I am using without the index there is no error, instead the entire array of incorrect_answers is being printed but the moment I enter the index and refresh the error show up.

But if I don't refresh and just save the file in my VS Code it is automatically updating in my browser. The moment I refresh it shows up with the error.

Kindly help me in this, I am struck here for a very long time now.

PS: Don't suggest Async,Await method.

Comment: initial state is an array, `answer.question` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

{answer.incorrect_answers && answer.incorrect_answers[0]}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you!! it worked. Can you please explain the reason also.

Comment: At initial state we checked that incorrect_answers present or not and if present then only return the incorrect_answers[0]. So only we added check here

Thanks

Comment: can you try this as well please:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71381789/checkbox-value-not-being-saved-in-localstorage-and-after-clicking-edit-item-the